# Noise removal from a recorded audio file in android

Tags: android, audio

everyone, I am new for android. Now, I am making an android app and I will record a file after playing the file and my own voice. However, there could be some noise in my wav file. Are there some library I can use for removing noise for my app ?

Comment: Are you talking about filters?

Comment: Yes, I want to filter the noise from my recorded wav file

Answer (score 1):

There are different kinds of noise, and how you get rid of it depends. There is no "magic bullet".

- To filter out certain frequencies, you can apply EQ. Roughly speaking, the parts of the signal necessary for clear understanding of speech fall in the range from 300 Hz - 3000 Hz. You can use EQ to eliminate everything below 300 Hz and above 3000 Hz. There are java libraries for this in [JSyn](http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/), and [processing](http://processing.org/).
- If your speech and noise occupy the same frequency bands, the problem becomes more difficult. There are a variety of techniques, generally under the heading of "broadband noise reduction". I'm not aware of any java library that does this at all, much less well, but you could do it in native code. I've never tried it, but [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) offers a "noisered" plugin that you could access from libsox.